# Calculate sum of total reputation on selected graph area

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

When in [this screen (current user -> reputation tab -> graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=reputation&sort=graph), you can "zoom in" a specific period of time to see what events occurred in that period of time.

Here's a snapshot of it
[image]

Can we add a small little field that also tells us **total sum of reputation for selected area**?

Comment: Can you maybe explain why this would be a useful feature?

Comment: @AndréKool is this part of a feature request template where we need to input obvious info? I mean, why would this be useful? Isn't it obvious?

Comment: It was a personal question but I'm going with the [tag description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) for justification of that question: _"Your question should contain the details of your proposal, **including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community.**"_ (emphisis mine)

Comment: I seem to recall trying to get this information just for kicks a while back. I was curious how much rep I had gained in my entire first year VS the last month. Not really any huge benefit, just for luls.

Comment: @AndréKool it says *should*. So, if wording and following template is more important than the idea behind the feature proposal, then downvote (which I think you already did). I don't care. I did my job (see something that can be improved and propose it)

Comment: I'd just go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, find the two dates and do some simple subtraction math....no programming required.

Comment: small * little == invisible. It is already there ;) I'd say `[Status-completed]`

Comment: @AndréKool In this case, though, I'd say it is quite obvious. This is not a change to site mechanics with potentially complex side-effects, or a correction of some subtly misleading aspect of the UI. It is just "please display this cool little thing".

Comment: That chart is made with Highcharts, which is just a charting tool. Doing such customisations using a charting tool is very hard if not impossible. On the other hand, if Stack Exchange sites used D3, which is a proper library (not a charting tool), such customisation would be a piece of cake (for a D3 programmer, of course).

Comment: Regarding the little argument above: it is an useful feature. Features that allow users to explore the data set and get other information and other aspects of it (like the total RP change in the brushed period, in this case) are almost always welcomed. Even if some users don't use it, it may be used by another ones, and that's what matters when we design a datavis.

Comment: Wouldn't an "Export Rep History to CSV" be a better option for data-wranglers? You can then use <insert-favourite-package> to analyse your data in any depth your like.